# How to select the largest variable in a dataset and assign it to a macro in sas

Tags: sas

Salutations, I need to take the largest value in a column. So I can turn it into a variable and use it in another query. something like.

```
%let maxyear = MAX(STay_yr)
```

help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use proc SQL and into:

```
proc sql;
  select max(STay_yr) into :maxyear
  from some_dataset;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

And another [david25272](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2640540/david25272)'s variant:

```
data _null_;
   set have end = last;
   retain max_STay_yr;
   if STay_yr > max_STay_yr then max_STay_yr = STay_yr;
   if last then call symput("maxyear",max_STay_yr);
run;
```

Variable `maxyear` will have the maximum value.

You can take the values from it further as `&maxyear`.

Comment: You have a problem if all values are negative, i.e. you shouldn't initialize `max_STay_yr`. Also, you can simplify your first `if` statement (line 4) to simply `max_STay_yr = max(max_STay_yr,STay_yr);`.

Comment: You are still initializing your retain variable - why? Your data step will return a wrong value if the true maximum is e.g. `-1e9`. `retain max_STay_yr;` works as expected.